# How do I make react component rerender when the State is changed?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

As you can see here. I first make an API call to get my data usage from the server, and then I store the response I got from the server to dataUsage by setting setDataUsage. However, I never got the accurate usedPercent in "{ name: 'Used', data:  usedPercent }", instead, I received a zero. How do I make sure this component takes the update and rerender once the API call has been finished?

```
const Piechart= () => {
    const userContext = useContext(UserContext)
    const history = useHistory()
    const [dataUsage, setDataUsage] = useState({
        upload: 0,
        redundancy: 0,
        usedData: 0,
        downloaded: 0,
        quoteData: 0,
        rank: 0
    });
    const [usedPercent, setUsedPercent] = useState(0);
  

    useEffect(() => {
        API().get('/mydatausage')
          .then(res => {
            const usage = res.data;
            setDataUsage({ upload:usage.up, redundancy:usage.red, usedData:usage.used, 
                downloaded:usage.dwn, quoteData:usage.quote, rank:usage.rnk });
          }).catch(err => {
            authErrorHandler(err, userContext.logoutHandler, history)
          })
      },[])

      const bToGbIndex = 1073741824;

      useEffect(
        () => {
          // if (componentDidUpdate & (x or y changed))
          setUsedPercent(dataUsage.usedData / bToGbIndex / dataUsage.quoteData);
        },
        [dataUsage]
      );

      const unUsedPercent = 100 - usedPercent;

      console.log(usedPercent)
      console.log(unUsedPercent)


  return(
    <>  
        <Donut
            chartData={[
                { name: 'Used', data:  usedPercent },
                { name: 'Free', data:  unUsedPercent }
            ]}
            chartWidth={300}
            chartHeight={500}
            title="Your Data Usage"
            chartThemeConfig={{
                series: {
                    colors: ['#ffe0bd', '#670303', '#6cbfce'],
                },
            }}
        />
    </>
  );
}

export default Piechart
```

Comment: Why do you have 'usageDataHandler' in your useEffect array?

Comment: @TreverThompson Sorry I just reformatted this code. If this makes more sense to you

Answer (score 0):

Your `usedPercent` can just be a simple variable inside the component:

```
const usedPercent = dataUsage.quoteData ? (dataUsage.usedData / bToGbIndex / dataUsage.quoteData) : 0;
```

Or if you want to memoize it (it's optional), use the React useMemo hook:

```
const { usedData, quoteData } = dataUsage;
const usedPercent = useMemo(() => quoteData ? (usedData / bToGbIndex / quoteData) : 0, [usedData, quoteData]);
```

You don't need to have a separate `useEffect` to update `usedPercent`. Think about `useEffect` as the old `componentDidUpdate` / `componentDidMount`, while it's possible to do multiple things inside `componentDidUpdate`, they shouldn't be dependent of each other. Avoid writing `useEffect` statements those are dependent of others.

In fact, as your `usedPercent` is derived / computed data from `dataUsage`, you don't have to make it a stateful variable either. If you want to keep your React component simple and maintainable, always try to keep the number of stateful data to minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using both `usedPercent and unUsedPercent` while rendering the component.

```
<Donut chartData={[
                { name: 'Used', data:  usedPercent },
                { name: 'Free', data:  unUsedPercent }
            ]}
       ...
```

So when you get `usedPercent` as zero then actaual state is not changed so component does not re-render\update.

Since you are using `usedPercent and unUsedPercent`, I would create one state variable even for `unUsedPercent` then your use effect should set this as below so that your component gets updated even when you get `usedPercent as zero`

```
const [unUsedPercent, setUnUsedPercent] = useState(0);

      useEffect(
        () => {
          // if (componentDidUpdate & (x or y changed))
          setUsedPercent(dataUsage.usedData / bToGbIndex / dataUsage.quoteData);
          const unUsedPercent = 100 - usedPercent;
          serUnUnsedPercent(unUsedPercent);
        },
        [dataUsage]
      );
```